# After deleting middle input renumber data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now when you add inputs they are numbered 1 by 1 so let's say we add 5 champions they will be numbered like

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

And let's say we want to remove 3rd one it will look like

- 1
- 2
- 4
- 5

And I want i to be numbered after removing like

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

Here is a working http://jsfiddle.net/dyje773m/ and also http://89.69.172.125/cms2.0/

Most important part of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    championNumberArray = 0;
    championNumber = 1;
    $('a#AddChampion').on('click',function(){
        $('div#ChampionInput').append(
        '<div class="Champion" data-id="'+championNumberArray+'">\
             <a href="#" class="Remove">Remove</a>\
             <br>\
             <input type="text" class="ChampionInput" list="champions" name="champion[]" placeholder="Champion '+championNumber+'">\
             <datalist id="champions"></datalist>\
             <a href="#" class="AddSpell">Add Spell</a>\
             <a href="#" class="AddGeneralChange">Add General Change</a>\
             <div class="GeneralChanges">\
             </div>\
             <div class="SpellChanges">\
             </div>\
             <br>\
         <div>');
        for(var key in champions){
            if(champions.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                $('#champions').append('<option value="' + key + '">');
            }
        }
        championNumberArray++;
        championNumber++;
    });
});
```

And index

```
<div id="wrap">
    <a href="#" id="AddChampion">Add Champion</a>
    <form name="second_form" id="second_form" method="POST">
        <div id="ChampionInput">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to renumber the inputs when you remove one. Try something like below.

```
$('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.Remove',function(){
    var champion = $(this).closest('.Champion');
    var id = champion.data("id");
    var nextChampion = champion;

    //
    // Loop through each following champion
    while((nextChampion = nextChampion.next()).length != 0){
        // Update id
        nextChampion.attr("data-id",id++)

        // Update placeholder
        // Placeholder is id + 1 because placholders start at 1 and ids start at 0
        nextChampion.find(".ChampionInput").attr("placeholder","Champion " + (id + 1));        
    }

    // Remove champion
    champion.remove();

});
```

By the way, you don't need to have the tagname before the selector. Especially for ids, which should be unique per page.  `#ChampionInput` is exactly like `div#ChampionInput`, except `#ChampionInput` is faster because the browser doesn't have to check if the tagName matches.

Comment: That works perfectly but is there any way to change quickly placeholde value accordingly?

Comment: I updated it so it also updates the placeholder. But it seems like you'll also have to change your add code so new champions input have the right placeholder. New champions probably get added with the wrong id too. If it's helpful, you can use `$(".ChampionInput").length` to get the number of Champions in order to calculate these values.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use championNumberArray and championNumber to store inputs quantities, instead of that u should count all the divs with class 'Champion' to get current quantity.

```
$("div.Champion").length;
```

when a input is added, u should set "id" value using previous method above.

---

when a input is deleted, u should get ther "id" value before removing... after removed, u can do following (( supposing "3" was removed ))

```
var c=3-1, el;

while(el=$("div.Champion:eq("+c+")").get())
{ $(el).data("id",c+1);  c++; }
```